# Application Insights not showing data in Azure Preview Portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an existing web application on Azure with some very limited application insights monitoring (end point checks). I thought I would pull in the rest of the functionality so I added telemetry to my project following the instructions at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/. Everything went well and I was able to see that when I loaded a page with the instrumentation JavaScript it was indeed sending requests to azure and I was getting back no errors either in error code or in the errors array in the json response.

The GUID in the applications insights configuration file looks correct. I've also tried sending telemetry manually

```
private void GatherTelemetry()
{
    var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
    telemetry.TrackEvent("FeedPageLoaded");
}
```

While all of these actions show up in the count in visual studio 
[image]

there is nothing in the portal.
[image]

I have tried reopening the blades as well as logging out and in again.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here are things to confirm:

1. if you are running your app from visual studio make sure there are events listed as sent from the output window (based on your screenshot above it looks good there)
2. make sure you are using our latest SDKs.  .11 had some breaking changes see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/10/21/application-insights-sdk-0-11-0-prerelease.aspx
3. ensure the events are being sent to the AI endpoint in fiddler dc.services.visualstudio.com (looks like you are good here)
4. go to portal.azure.com and choose browse -> application insights and choose the app you are sending data for.  you can double check by looking at the instrumentation key on the properties part.  another way to get back to the portal is through the deep links made available in visual studio.  on the overview blade go to the diagnostic search part to see a tail of the last telemetry events collected.
5. finally if you don't see data check for service issues here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: I went back into the portal today and found that I had data being logged. Perhaps there was a glitch when I set this up initially. I'm still not seeing the custom events I defined showing up but I think that might be an interpretation problem on my part. I was expecting the "Events in the Past Week" lens to show these but that is for Azure events. That could be clearer or I could be smarter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that custom events aren't yet included in the charts you are looking at.  Have you checked whether you can find the events using the search functionality?

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting custom events to show up in the "Events in the Past Week" lens but that's not the right expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Custom events will soon be seen in the overview blade.  In the mean time you can chart the trend of  metric Event count.  Just select any chart and open up Metric Explorer, then you can select the metric Event count.  This should show you the trend of events sent.