# Application Insights is showing no data at all

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am experimenting with Application Insights (v0.14.0) and an ASP.NET application that I maintain, and I am finding its data collecting to be quite erratic. For a while, I was only getting client-side data being published (e.g. Browser Page Load Time) but none of the server metrics. I checked that the ApplicationInsights.config file was in both the web root folder and in the bin folder as per [Application Insights not showing data in Azure Preview Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808530/application-insights-not-showing-data-in-azure-preview-portal), and that the correct instrumentation key was being used. We are not currently running the AI agent application.

Last night we deployed a new version of our application, without changing the AI configuration, and suddenly the server metrics started coming in. Hurrah! Unfortunately, 45 minutes later we deployed a single assembly hotfix to the application, and after the app pools had been recycled, the server metrics stopped, and this time the client metrics stopped as well.

Opening up the web application in my browser, I can see the AI.js script being loaded, and looking at the outbound network calls, I can see the telemetry being successfully submitted to AI:

```
Remote Address:23.101.207.84:443
Request URL:https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

Any ideas what's going on?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately yesterday we had issue in the pipeline, that was causing latency of upto 4 hours.  You can always get information on the service at http://aka.ms/aistatus.  We are still working through some of the issues, but they are mostly resolved.

Comment: I checked again today, and now my screens are full of lovely metrics, both client and server side!